# Why does strip() fix this pexpect script?

Tags: regex, python, expect, pexpect

I have an object.

This object has a `connect()` method which spawns a pexpect process.

The process that's spawned is a custom serial interface. On launch, this tool prints a menu of serial devices to connect to, like so:

> ```
> libftdi device (0): A6005jpt
> libftdi device (1): acFX9DQf
> Serial device (a) : /dev/cu.Bluetooth-PDA-Sync
> Select a device by its letter (^D to abort):
> ```

My `connect()` determines which number to pass based on a given devicename (e.g. 'acFX9DQf'): (self.connection is the pexpect spawn)

```
USBSERIAL_DEVICE_NAME = "acFX9DQf"    

try:
    while self.connection.expect(['libftdi device \(([0-9])\): (.*)','Serial device']) == 0:
        if self.connection.match.group(2).strip() == USBSERIAL_DEVICE_NAME:
            # do stuff
except:
    # do stuff
```

Now, my problem is that I `connect()`/`kill()` the process multiple times in my main logic and sometimes, one of those times, `connect()` decides to throw a [`pexpect.TIMEOUT`](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html#TIMEOUT) exception, unexpectedly.

For example, when I add the following debug statements to my logic, like so:

```
USBSERIAL_DEVICE_NAME = "acFX9DQf"

try:
    while self.connection.expect(['libftdi device \(([0-9])\): (.*)','Serial device'], timeout=10) == 0:
        print "MATCHED A DEVICE LINE!"
        if self.connection.match.group(2).strip() == USBSERIAL_DEVICE_NAME:
            print "MATCHED THE DESIRED USBSERIAL..."
```

...I get this output for many calls of `connect()`:

> ```
> libftdi device (0): A6005jpt
> MATCHED A DEVICE LINE!
> libftdi device (1): acFX9DQf
> MATCHED A DEVICE LINE!
> MATCHED THE DESIRED USBSERIAL...
> Serial device (a) : /dev/cu.Bluetooth-PDA-Sync
> Select a device by its letter (^D to abort): 1
> ```

...then, one of my `connect()` calls will unexpectedly do....

> ```
> libftdi device (0): A6005jpt
> MATCHED A DEVICE LINE!
> libftdi device (1): acFX9DQf
> Serial device (a) : /dev/cu.Bluetooth-PDA-Sync
> Select a device by its letter (^D to abort): MATCHED A DEVICE LINE!
>
> <<EXCEPTION>>
> ```

But, if I revise my code to this:

```
try:
    while self.connection.expect(['libftdi device \(([0-9])\): (.*)','Serial device'], timeout=10) == 0:
        devicename = self.connection.match.group(2).strip()
        if devicename == USBSERIAL_DEVICE_NAME:
            # do stuff
```

My problems go away! I can run it repeatedly and no problems will occur - no exceptions, no nothin'.

So wot in the heck is going on here? I'm not even sure where to begin with this problem.

Comment: OK, so what exception are you getting and what change fixes it?

Comment: When you introduce `devicename`, is the output ever the same as for when the first code fails (that is, the "MATCHED A DEVICE LINE!" comes after the prompt)?

Comment: @Gabe - I was getting a pexpect.TIMEOUT.

Comment: @outis - It always fails randomly. My main business logic connect()/kills() 7 times. Sometimes connect() throws the exception on time 1 or time 4. It's weird.

Comment: that doesn't answer my question. I was asking about the behavior of code that you say you can "run [...] repeatedly and no problems will occur." Does it show the same output as when the first code fails? The reason I ask is to figure out why it isn't failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're getting a `TIMEOUT` exception. Based on where the "MATCHED A DEVICE LINE!" message is in the output, my hypothesis is that the `spawn` instance has multiple lines when it tests for a match. When pexpect compiles the regexes, it [sets `re.DOTALL`](http://pexpect.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pexpect/trunk/pexpect/pexpect.py?revision=525&view=markup#l1223), so the `.*` includes the newline and the additional lines. This causes the test against `USBSERIAL_DEVICE_NAME` to fail and the loop continues its next iteration. The next call to `expect` blocks because there is no additional input and you get a timeout.

To fix this, you can pass in your own compiled regexes (which will lack the `re.DOTALL` flag) or change the `.*` so it explicitly doesn't match the newline (e.g. `\S*`).

As for why storing the matched group in a variable seems to fix things, I can only guess this introduces a subtle timing change that prevents the call to `expect` from receiving multiple lines of input at once.

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution. My guess was it was a timing/pexpect bugginess thing. Just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing some key Python lesson here...

Comment: Changing .* to \S* fixed it!! Perfect answer!

Comment: @eastydude: timing, yes, bug, no. pexpect's use of `re.DOTALL` is designed. I don't know the reason, but it was probably to fix a bug.